# Golang http redirect Strange behavior

Tags: http, redirect, go

I have a login page (login.html) that uses Javascript to call a golang service on the back end. Upon successful login, the user should be taken to a dashboard page (dashboard.html). Instead, the dashboard page opens up in the middle of the login page as shown here:

[image: Page within a Page instead of Redirect]

The relevant code is:

```
func userhandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, subcommand string) {
...

// If the credentials are valid, go to the Dashboard page
if validateLoginCredentials([]byte(loginUsername), []byte(loginPassword)) != -1 {

http.Redirect(w, r, "/dashboard.html", 302) //<<<<<<<<<The Redirect is here

}
...
}

func webhandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) { ...
// Service the API
if strings.HasPrefix(r.URL.Path, "/xyzzy/") {
    urlparts := strings.SplitN(r.URL.Path, "/", 5) ...
        switch urlparts[3] {
            case "user":
                userhandler(w, r, urlparts[4]) ...
        }
    }
} else { // Serve the static pages
    http.FileServer(http.Dir(".")).ServeHTTP(w, r)
}

... 
}

func main {
...
http.HandleFunc("/", webhandler) ...
err_https := http.ListenAndServeTLS(":3001", "./xyzzy.crt", "./xyzzy.key", nil)
... 
}
```

If, as a test, I put the redirect into the spot where it serves the static pages (all static pages will redirect to the dashboard page), it looks like it works. But, in the code that handles the user api functions, like login, I get this behavior.

HTML Snippet:

```
<body>
    <div class="logintopspacer" id="logintopspacerid"></div>
    <div class="loginlogo" id="loginlogoid"><img src="img/pixmover1.png" alt="PixMover" width="270"></div>
    <div class="logintitlecontainer" id="logintitlecontainerid">
        <div class="logintitle" id="logintitleid">User Login</div>
    </div>
    <div class="loginmidspacer" id="loginmidspacerid"></div>
    <div class="logincredentialscontainer" id="logincredentialscontainerid">
        <div class="logincredentialsspacer"></div>
        <div class="logincredentialtitle">Username/Email:</div>
        <div class="logincredentialentry"><input type="text" name="pixun" id="pixunid" size="25"></div>
        <div class="logincredentialsspacer"></div>

        <div class="logincredentialsspacer"></div>
        <div class="logincredentialtitle">Password:</div>
        <div class="logincredentialentry"><input type="password" name="pixpw" id="pixpwid" size="25"></div>
        <div class="logincredentialsspacer"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="loginbuttoncontainer" id="loginbuttoncontainerid">
        <div class="loginbutton" id="loginbuttonid" onmousedown="buttonPressed();" onmouseup="submitForm();" onmouseout="buttonReleased();" >Login</div>
    </div>
    <div class="loginerrormessage" id="loginerrormessageid"></div>
    <div class="loginbottomspacer" id="loginbottomspacerid"></div>

    <div class="pagefooter" id="pagefooterid">
        Copyright &copy; XYZZY, Inc. 2016
    </div>

</body>
```

Javascript:

```
function submitForm()
{
    document.getElementById("loginbuttonid").className = "loginbutton";
    pixlogin();
}

function pixlogin()
{
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200)
        {
            document.getElementById("loginerrormessageid").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
        }
    };

    xhttp.open("POST", "pixmover/1_0_0/user/login", true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhttp.send("username=" + document.getElementById("pixunid").value + "&password=" + document.getElementById("pixpwid").value);
}
```

Comment: Are you using any sort of templating package or front end framework e.g. Angular / React / EmberJS?

Comment: No. This is on Windows, if that makes any difference. It's straight HTML and Javascript. This is in development, and I'm using https://localhost:3001/login.html as the URL. Everything is running on the same machine.

Comment: Can you include the small snippet of JavaScript and html that processes the login

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is coming from your

```
if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200)
{
    document.getElementById("loginerrormessageid").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
}
```

When the redirect comes back you're getting the entire page and it's just loading it in to the error message because there is no conditionals. You might want to do something instead like

```
if (isAuthenticated) {
    location.href = "/"; // whatever page to redirect to
}
```

Comment: You're brilliant. Thanks. Still developing that page, and haven't taken care of the error condition yet. That behavior kind of freaked me out.

Comment: @user1426181 Right on, gl!

Comment: Actually, I'm still stuck on this. Yes, it is filling the div with the contents of the page, but I'm still trying to figure out why it's doing this. For some reason, it's not changing the http status code to a redirect, which I have as a 302. The line: http.Redirect(w, r, "/dashboard.html", 302) is not causing a 302. I'd like to figure that out, but I'll take your suggestion and do the location.href solution.

Comment: @user1426181 I'm not sure on my terminology 100% but it's because you're passing the data through your xmlhttprequest. If you were to physically visit the page that would work just fine and it would redirect you, but because of the method you're using its passing all the relevant information through the object

Comment: @user1426181 instead of sending a redirect, send a json object if it was successful, something like `success: true` then do a location.href based on the result

Comment: Yep, I'm going to do that in the interim. the http request should handle other response codes. This is what's there to handle a 200:                     if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200), and I'd think that this would fail for a 302 redirect. The problem may be from the golang end, where it's not generating the 302 in the header. I don't know, I'm a little confused, but I will take your advice and go with the location.href method. Thanks for your help on this.